# Create boxplots from separate data frames with different number of rows

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I'm trying to make a data frame to then create a boxplot from. The data frame should contain 3 vectors of varying sizes. Let's say the data is currently in `a$data`, `b$data` and `c$data`, and are of lengths 7, 50, 200.

Here is a simplified version of my code, where the `cbind` step errors:

```
# create initial df
    df <- data.frame()
# set column names
    colnames(df) <- c("a", "b", "c")
# bind original data to new data frame: 
    df <- cbind(df, a$data, b$data, c$data)
# draw boxplot
    boxplot(df)
```

Comment: `df <- data.frame` creates a *function* exactly equal to function `data.frame`. In R, this is the same as `x <- 1; y <- x`. The objects `x` and `y` are now `identical()`. See what `identical(df, data.frame)` returns. Can you post the output of `dput(head(a$data))`?

Comment: Perhaps it's just your sample code, but `df` here would be a *function*, not a data object. (Perhaps I'm being too literal with your sample data.) Further, you cannot `cbind` frames of different numbers of rows ... okay, you sometimes can get away with it, but if it doesn't warn or error, *you should be concerned* (and more careful).

Comment: @RuiBarradas - sure, look like: `c(7.8192479, 7.910274, 7.51289579, 7.189279, 7.5897185, 7.14218948)`

Comment: Apologies, data.frame was indeed just an example, I'll edit it now.

Comment: A `data.frame` can't "_contain [...] vectors of varying sizes_". But lists can, e.g. `l = list(x = rnorm(5, 2), y = rnorm(10, 3), z = rnorm(20, 1))`. And `boxplot` happily eats lists: ; `boxplot(l)`.

Comment: @Henrik That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.frame` can *not* "contain [...] vectors of varying sizes". But lists can, e.g.

`l = list(x = rnorm(5, 2), y = rnorm(10, 3), z = rnorm(20, 1))`.

And `boxplot` happily eats lists:

`boxplot(l)`
[image]

Comment: I am among today's [10,000 people](https://xkcd.com/1053/). (Not that I use base R boxplots much these days, but ... how did I not know this?)

Comment: Do not despair @r2evans, this winter is the suitable time to find yourself in the Chesterfield armchair with your favorite Burgundy red and...The R Reference Index.

Comment: Yes, that manual is ... riveting ... action sequences unequaled by anything except perhaps Webster's Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code and see if it solves the problem.
It creates a data set in the long format, with a column vector of variables `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"`, and their respective values. Then plots the data with the formula interface.

```
variable <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 
                c(length(a$data),length(b$data), length(c$data)))
value <- c(a$data, b$data, c$data)

df <- data.frame(variable, value)
boxplot(value ~ variable, data = df)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to think of groups of boxplots in a "long-data" sense.

Fake-data:

```r
set.seed(2021)
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10)); df2 <- data.frame(x=runif(20)); df3 <- data.frame(x=runif(100))
head(df1,3); head(df2,3); head(df3,3)
#           x
# 1 0.4512674
# 2 0.7837798
# 3 0.7096822
#            x
# 1 0.02726706
# 2 0.83749040
# 3 0.60324073
#            x
# 1 0.03277595
# 2 0.94270937
# 3 0.94773844
```

Combine into one long frame:

```r
# tidyverse
dfall <- dplyr::bind_rows(dplyr::lst(df1, df2, df3), .id = "id")

# data.table
dfall <- rbindlist(list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3), idcol = "id")

# base R
lst_of_frames <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
lst_of_frames <- Map(function(x,nm) transform(x, { id = nm }), lst_of_frames, names(lst_of_frames))
dfall <- do.call(rbind, lst_of_frames)
```

Plot:

```r
boxplot(x ~ id, data = dfall)
```

[image: simple boxploot]